# VirtualBox to share clipboard and files

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, clipboard, dkms

I use `VirtualBox 5.2.6` on `Windows 10`. There is an `Ubuntu` virtual machine, from which I would like to access to host's clipboard and files.
I tried to use

> Machine>Settings >> General>Advanced>Shared Clipboard

I also tried

> Devices>Shared Clipboard>Bidirectional

I installed `virtualbox-guest-dkms` too, but has no effect.

Comment: Did you check if you are able to copy paste text?

Comment: @TarunLalwani : It isn't working too.

Comment: Can you try installing `https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.6.vbox-extpack` and see if that helps?

Comment: Extension pack is "only" required to boot on lan, and have usb2 and usb3 support, please note that clipboard share is a native component in Vbox, assuming that guest addition is succesfully installed in VM

Comment: If you just tested in the terminal please notice that **Ctrl+c** is for break you should use *Ctrl+Shift+C* And **Ctrl+Shift+V** for copy and paste. for me it works well, I should mention that I have the **guest addition** installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need first to install [guest addition](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) in your VM, you may take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/how-do-i-enable-the-shared-clipboard-in-virtualbox) if you need help.

Comment: don't forget to shut down the virtual machine and reboot your physical host computer in order changes to take effect

Answer (score 2):

I've been fighting with this issue. There's a lot of writting about this, some solutions work for some causes and others do the fix for others.

I just want to share how I fixed this at all. Hoping this will help at least for some cases.
First of all, update your guest Ubuntu SO.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Then, install guest addition as @A STEFANI stated.
This will install the program VBoxClient-all in the guest machine.

After this, just kill the proccess VBoxClient and start it using VBoxClient-all.

```
$ sudo killall VBoxClient
$ VBoxClient-all
```

No reboot is needed.
Hope this helps.